# Issue with contentOffset

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiwebview

Right now i'm working on an app which uses a custom splitView, it has a `PDFTableController` which represents the rootViewController and popover table and I have `AffirmaPDFViewController` which represents the detailViewController.

The way the interface is set up is that there is a scrollView and within the scrollView there are three WebViews which load up PDFs to be viewed.  These WebViews have a width of 1024px and placed side by side to allow swiping.

When I select an item from the table I return both the item selected and the row number, because I need to change the origin of the scrollView by a multiplier which is represented the row number.  my code is as seen below:

```
start = ((i) * 1024);

        NSLog(@"%d", start);
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(webView1.frame.origin.x + start, webView1.frame.origin.y);
```

`i` is the row number which is provided by the `PDFTableController`.  The `start` variable comes out with the appropriate value, (0, 1024, 2048, etc) and the scrollView moves.  However it does not change which webView is being shown.  Anyone know why this is?

To set up the webViews I used IB, however I change some properties when rotation occurs:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    counter = 0;
    webView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    webView2.frame = CGRectMake(768, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    webView3.frame = CGRectMake(1536, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    isLandscape = NO;
}
else {
    counter = 0;
    webView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 724);
    webView2.frame = CGRectMake(1024, 0, 1024, 724);
    webView3.frame = CGRectMake(2048, 0, 1024, 724);
    isLandscape = YES;
}

[webView1 reload];
[webView2 reload];
[webView3 reload];

}
```

The [`________ reload];` calls are there because of an issue with webViews loading PDF's and rotation, a bit of a stretch I know, but this is the only fix I've been able to find

I'm loading the content to the webViews by:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"affirma" ofType:@"pdf"]];
[webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL]];

pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recursion" ofType:@"pdf"]];
[webView2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL]];

pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"review" ofType:@"pdf"]];
[webView3 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL]];
}
```

2011-05-31 10:38:16.465 AffirmaPDF[1927:207] {{1.17666e-40, 3.4481e-36}, {1.35492e-41, -1.99922}}

2011-05-31 10:38:16.467 AffirmaPDF[1927:207] {{2.98701e-41, 1.35492e-41}, {0, -1.99921}}

2011-05-31 10:38:16.468 AffirmaPDF[1927:207] {{2.19627e-37, 3.4481e-36}, {3.48195e-41, 3.4481e-36}}

2011-05-31 10:38:16.469 AffirmaPDF[1927:207] {{2.19615e-37, 2.55515e-39}, {2.19615e-37, -1.99921}}

2011-05-31 10:38:16.470 AffirmaPDF[1927:207] {0, 0}

2011-05-31 10:38:16.470 AffirmaPDF[1927:207] {0, 0}

Comment: Can you show how you set up the webviews?

Comment: I just put up the code for the webViews, with this code, resizing when rotating the ipad works correctly.

Comment: the webViews are all children of the scrollView

Comment: Is it the same web view or the same content? If content, how are you loading them?

Comment: I jus thew up the code to load the content onto the webViews

Comment: So you're see only able to see one of these pdf's right?

Comment: yeah, there is only one webView being displayed on the screen at once.  However the other two are already loaded and always there, they are just off-screen

Comment: That part I did understand. Can you elaborate `and the scrollView moves. However it does not change which webView is being shown.`?

Comment: After looking at my code I realized that, that statement is incorrect.  My scrollView.frame.origin.x always remains at 0.  Does ContentOffset, simply change the origin of the child views?  What exactly does it do?

Comment: It doesn't affect the origin of the children. Imagine a canvas bigger than the frame, contentOffset just tells you which part of it is on screen.

Comment: So shouldn't what I have technically work?

Comment: Is it because when I resize the webViews when I rotate, it is basically overwriting the ContentOffset?

Comment: This should technically work. And if this were to do anything with rotation. Can you add [`this code`](http://pastie.org/1999229) after you change the offset and post the output?

Comment: Where did you add this? Just after the first piece of code in the problem, right?

Comment: I added it right after `scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(webView1.frame.origin.x + start, webView1.frame.origin.y);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the garbage values, it looks like the scroll view and the web views haven't been added to the view hierarchy or they haven't been connected via outlets.

Comment: All the outlets are connected in IB.  I have two .xib files.  MainWindow, and AffirmaPDFViewController.xib.  Do I need to add a view to MainWindow.xib and have that view load AffirmaPDFViewController?

Comment: Which method are you executing the first piece of code in? The output at the end just doesn't make sense.

Comment: In the `- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {` method

Comment: Can post the interface file with the relevant parts?

Comment: But have you connected the `scrollView` property to the `UIScrollView` object in the nib?

Comment: In my .h file, I have `UIScrollView *scrollView;` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView` and then in the .m file I am synthesizing scrollView

Comment: do `scrollView.frame = CGRectZero;` in `setDetailItem:` and check if the frame changes? If it doesn't, you haven't wired the outlets.

Comment: yeah scrollView doesn't change.  Do I have to do anything in MainWindow.xib? all my connections and everything happen in AffirmaPDFViewController.xib.  I just have a window that is linked to the AffirmaPDFAppDelegate in MainWindow.xib

Comment: Since you are saying custom split view controller, how did you set it up?

Comment: I have `AffirmaPDFViewController` (.xib, .h, .m), with a navigationBar, a barButtonItem, scrollView, webView1, webView2, and webView3.  When the user pushes the barButtomItem, a popover with a tableViewController appears with a list of PDF's to chose from. and a `PDFTableController` (.h, .m) which represents the tableViewController.  In `MainWindow.xib` I have the `App Delegate` with available outlets to `affirmaPDFController`, `pdfTableController`, and window.  `affirmaPDFController` is linked to `AffirmaPDFController`, and window is linked to Window, but `pdfTableController` is left blank.

Comment: Is `AffirmaPDFController` the split view?

Comment: There isn't an actual UISplitViewController.  Sorry if that was misleading.  What I meant was that, it was like a splitView in that it had the popover table and that instead of there being a static table in landscape mode, it remained as a button in the navigation bar with a popover

Comment: How do you set the reference to the `AffirmaPDFViewController` instance in the `pdfTableController`? And are`AffirmaPDFViewController` and `AffirmaPDFController` the same?

Comment: yeah sorry there isn't an `AffirmaPDFController` they are all `AffirmaPDFViewController`.  I don't set any reference to AffirmaPDFViewController in pdfTableController.  In the PDFTableController.m I have: `affirmaPDFViewController = [[AffirmaPDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AffirmaPDFViewController" bundle:nil];` but that is the only reference to AffirmaPDFViewController found in PDFTableController.

Comment: Remove it. I am thinking `affirmaPDFViewController` is declared as a property in `PDFTableController`. So when you are instantiating the `PDFTableController` instance, do `pdfTableController.affirmaPDFViewController = self.affirmaPDFViewController;` (It will be `self` if you are doing it in `AffirmaPDFViewController.m`). This way you link it to the existing instance of `AffirmaPDFViewController` and not create a new instance.

Comment: to do this in `AffirmaPDFViewController.m` do I need to make an `affirmaPDFViewController` property in order to assign `pdfTableController.affirmaViewController = self.affirmaPDFVIewController;`?

Comment: Do you instantiate `pdfTableController` in AffirmaPDFViewController.m or the app delegate?

Comment: You will need a property for `affirmaPDFViewController` in `PDFTableController`.

Comment: And if you are instantiating the delegate's `pdfTableController` in the app delegate, do `pdfTableController.affirmaPDFViewController = self.affirmaPDFViewController;`.

Comment: I get an error saying "Request for member 'affirmaPDFVIewController' in something not a structure or union".

the line of code I put in is: 
`- (void)viewDidLoad {
 
 PDFTableController.affirmaPDFViewController = self.affirmaPDFViewController;`

Comment: Where did you put this ? Did you define a property for it in `PDFTableController`?

Comment: I put the line in the `viewDidLoad` method in `AffirmaPDFViewController`.  Yeah I defined the property in `PDFTableController` but I don't have the property in `AffirmaPDFViewController` should I put it in there too?